# Is it possible to use the result of the last calculation directly ？ Java Synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Why is the Synchronized block able to directly use the previous calculation result when two consecutive requests to factorize the same value?

code from 2-8 of Java Concurrency in Practice

```
    public class two_8_CachedFactorizer  implements Servlet {
    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger lastNumber;
    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger[] lastFactors;
    @GuardedBy("this") private long hits;
    @GuardedBy("this") private long cacheHits;

    public synchronized long getHits(){return hits;}
    public synchronized double getCacheHitRatio(){
        return (double) cacheHits/(double)hits;
    }
    @Override
    public  void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        BigInteger i=extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors=null;
        synchronized (this) {
            ++hits;
            if (i.equals(lastNumber)) {
                ++cacheHits;
                factors = lastFactors.clone();
            }
        }
            if (factors==null)
            {
                factors=factor(i);//question in here ：Suppose two identical requests arrive here at the same time
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    lastNumber=i;
                    lastFactors=factors.clone();
                }
            }
            encodeIntoResponse(res,factors);
        }

}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? If you want one thread to wait for the other because they both compute the same value, then in the book your mentioned; there is going to be such an implementation with Future.

Comment: Where are `lastFactors`, `cacheHits`, etc. defined? Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have at least a race condition on your hand. It could be that a earlier issued `factor(i)` completes after a later issued `factor(i)`; overwritting the value of the later issued `factor(i)`. So the lastFactor and lastNumber could be updated to an earlier version. To resolve that problem I would add some checking in the last synchronized block.

In the current code, you can have multiple threads doing the same calculation. I'm not sure if that is desirable.

Comment: Thank you, sir ,Will double-counting occur in factor() when two requests contain the same "i"? Suppose this "i" has never appeared before

Comment: If i=10 is issued first and then i=1000. If i=1000 completes before i=10, lastNumber will become 10 and not 1000.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your requirements. But if you want to cache the values, I would use a ConcurrentMap with 'i' as key and a CompletableFuture as value. But be careful letting the cache grow without limits.

Comment: The purpose of the code doesn't seem to be efficient or "correct" (whatever that may mean in this context). It just seems to cache the last calculation, it's possible to perform the same calculation on multiple threads or cache any factor (not just the largest). I assume this is a JCIP example "this is how to do multithreaded things in a weirdly wrong way".